# Is the python package panda without s malicious?

Tags: python, package, pypi

I just downloaded the package `panda` ([Pypi page of panda](https://pypi.org/project/panda/0.3.1/)) without `s` instead of the actual `pandas`. Is this a malicious package basically typo-squatting or just a coincidence? Interestingly the real `pandas` is just a few weeks older than `panda`. `panda` was initially released in early 2010 and occasionally maintained until August 2015. It claims to be Python implementation of the Panda REST interface.

Do I need to worry about anything here?

Comment: If you have installed, I would suggest to check the installed location and inspect the source to see what it does.

Comment: Looks like the source is available in [Github](https://github.com/pandastream/panda_client_python#setup)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Ahhh thanks will check the source!